# Deligne-Hitchin twistor space

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry, hodge-theory

Let $M$ be the moduli space of stable holomorphic Higgs bundles on a Riemann surface $\Sigma$. By Hitchin s work it is equipped with a hyper-kaehler structure, and one can define its twistor space, a holomorphic fibration $M_{DH}\to P^1$ which is diffeomorphic (as real manifolds) to $M\times P^1.$ 
Simpson (building on ideas of Deligne) explains a construction of the space  $M_{DH}$ without using the self-duality equations (as Hitchin did), see e.g. "A weight two phenomenon for the moduli ...".
He uses the notion of $\lambda (\in\mathbb C)$ connections, holomorphic bundles equipped with flat differential operators satisfying the $\lambda\partial$ Leibniz rule holds. The space  $M_{DH}$ can be constructed by gluing the moduli space of $\lambda$ connections on $\Sigma$ with the the moduli space of $\lambda$ connections on $\bar\Sigma.$ Solutions of the self duality equations correspond to certain $\sigma$ invariant sections of $M_{DH}\to P^1$.

As far as I understand this construction it is crucial to know that the relative tangent bundle of a $\sigma$ invariant section is $\mathcal O(1)^d:$ namely one can use this observation to define the hyper-kaehler structure on the space of $\sigma$ invariant sections. Has anybody a detailed and direct explanation for the identification of the relative tangent bundle as $\mathcal O(1)^d,$ (Simpson only mentions this property).